# Insert column into Google sheet generated from a Google form to calculate the difference between two columns of data

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a Google form where people track their company mileage and input "Mileage In" and "Mileage Out."

I want to insert a column next to Mileage In and Mileage Out that shows the difference between those numbers, which would be the total miles driven by that user.

I understand that I should be using an array formula and have tried to use one from this article: https://www.benlcollins.com/formula-examples/array-formulas-forms/

I inserted a column next to the two mileage columns and put this formula in the header:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(ISBLANK($O$2:$O),"",SUM("$N$2:$N"-"$M$2:$M")))
```

It doesn't work and returns an error about circular dependency.

I don't understand this formula well enough to continue troubleshooting on my own. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(O2:O), QUERY(M2:N, "select N-M label N-M''"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I try to use that formula exactly as written, I get  this error: "Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings."

Comment: I can't share a copy because it would be breaking confidentiality rules at my job, but I can reproduce something similar with dummy data and then post.

Comment: Here you go. Let me know if you need anything else:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lzA_L3e-GmZGOBIzI_nSQz7W3RZ2gnrAoQDGM7udFj0/edit?usp=sharing

Please note that THIS document is just a copy of the other sheet, and it is not connected to a google form. However, the real sheet I am using is connected to a google form, which will be continuously updated. Thanks again.

Comment: your "Mileage In" and "Mileage Out" columns (M, N) are empty. also, where you want that sum (if they wouldn't be empty) ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j1f9pJTS-a4TfZsAK5iiVeLIIu8Ktlwclm7s9k9J4Po/edit#gid=1742353707

Comment: Fantastic! I was able to make this work! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

={"ARRAYFORMULA IS HERE";ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(P2:P), QUERY(N2:O, "select O-N label O-N''"), ))}

From [user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0) :D Thank you!